# how can we proof $\partial\Delta^n$ (boundary of standard $n$-simplex) consists in the intersections of $\Delta^n$ with the hyperplanes $t_i= 0$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am trying to show the boundary of standard $n$-simplex  consists in the intersections of $\Delta^n$ with the hyperplanes $t_i= 0$
Here, the standard $n$-simplex is given by
$$ \Delta^n = \left\{ (t_0x_0+t_1x_1+\cdots+t_nx_n)\in \Bbb{R}^{n}\ :\ \sum t_i = 1,\ t_i\geq 0\right\}$$
with x0,x1,x2,...,xn in Rn
x1 - x0 ,x2-x0,...,xn-x0 are n linearly independent
Any help will be appreciated.
thank you

Comment: it mean boundary of Δn in Rn+1

Comment: oh sr i will fix it

Answer (score 0):

By applying a translation on $\mathbb{R}^n$, we may assume $x_0=0$.  By applying an invertible linear transformation, we may then assume that $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  In that case, we have $$\Delta^n=\left\{(t_1,\dots,t_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n:\sum_{i=1}^n t_i\leq 1, t_i\geq 0\right\}.$$
We wish to show that the boundary of this set consists of its intersections with the hyperplanes $H_i$ defined by $t_i=0$ and the hyperplane $H_0$ defined by $\sum_1^n t_i=1$ (this corresponds to $t_0=0$).  This follows from the following facts:

1. $\Delta^n$ is closed, so $\partial\Delta^n\subseteq \Delta^n$.
2. The set $\Delta^n\setminus \bigcup_{i=0}^n H_i=\{(t_1,\dots,t_n):\sum t_i<1, t_i>0\}$ is open, so $\partial\Delta^n\subseteq \bigcup H_i$.
3. No point in any $H_i$ is in the interior of $\Delta^n$, so $\Delta^n\cap\bigcup H_i\subseteq \partial\Delta^n$.

I will demonstrate (3) in the case $i=1$, and leave it to you to verify (1) and (2) and the general case of (3) (in particular, the case $i=0$ of (3) requires a slightly different argument).  Suppose you have a point $p=(0,t_2,\dots, t_n)\in H_1$ and $U$ is an open set containing $p$.  Then for some $\epsilon>0$, the point $p'=(-\epsilon,t_2,\dots,t_n)$ is also in $U$.  But $p'\not\in\Delta^n$, so $U\not\subseteq\Delta^n$.  Since $U$ was arbitrary, this means $p$ is not an interior point of $\Delta^n$.